# Wordpress/html integration 'duplication of footer'

Tags: html, wordpress, duplicates, footer

Can anybody please help me. I have been trying to integrate a html template with Wordpress. Everything seems to be working fine apart from the footer.
The footer keeps to be duplicating itself. 
I have created a Wordpress header and footer in a starkers bare bones theme and there is only one footer in the code that I have written.
looking at the source code, I can see that there is a second footer being introduced at line 144/145, though this is not in the code that I have written. Where is it coming from?

I am afraid this is on my local server, so I cannot provide a link right now.

My header:

```html
<?php
/**
 * The Header for our theme.
 *
 * Displays all of the <head> section
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Starkers
 * @since Starkers HTML5 3.0
 */
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head>
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>" />
<!-- Mobile Specific Metas
 ================================================== -->
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
<title><?php
 
    global $page, $paged;
 
    wp_title( '|', true, 'right' );
 
    bloginfo( 'name' );
 
    $site_description = get_bloginfo( 'description', 'display' );
    if ( $site_description && ( is_home() || is_front_page() ) )
        echo " | $site_description";
 
    if ( $paged >= 2 || $page >= 2 )
        echo ' | ' . sprintf( __( 'Page %s', 'starkers' ), max( $paged, $page ) );
 
    ?></title>
<link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="<?php bloginfo( 'stylesheet_url' ); ?>" />
<link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>" />
 
<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/modernizr-1.6.min.js"></script>

 
<?php
    /* We add some JavaScript to pages with the comment form
     * to support sites with threaded comments (when in use).
     */
    if ( is_singular() && get_option( 'thread_comments' ) )
        wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' );
 
    /* Always have wp_head() just before the closing </head>
     * tag of your theme, or you will break many plugins, which
     * generally use this hook to add elements to <head> such
     * as styles, scripts, and meta tags.
     */
    wp_head();
?>
</head>
 
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
 
    <header>



    
    <!-- Primary Page Layout 
 ================================================== -->
 <!-- globalWrapper -->
 <div id="globalWrapper">
  <header class="navbar-fixed-top">
   <!-- pre header -->
   
   <!-- pre header -->
   <!-- header -->
   <div id="mainHeader" role="banner">
    <div class="container">
     <nav class="navbar navbar-default scrollMenu" role="navigation">
      <div class="navbar-header">
       <!-- responsive navigation -->
       <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
       </button>
       <!-- Logo -->
                                                        
       <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/includes/images/logo.png" alt="blah"/></a>
      </div>
                                                
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="mainMenu">
       <!-- Main navigation -->
       <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
                                                            <li><a href="#">link 1</a></li>
                                                            <li><a href="#">link 2</a></li>
                                                            <li><a href="#">link 3</a></li>
                                                            <li><a href="#">link 4</a></li>
                                                            <li><a href="#">link 5</a></li>
                                                        </ul>
       <!-- End main navigation -->
      </div>
     </nav>
    </div>
   </div>
  </header>
         <!-- header -->
                        
        </header>
```

My footer:

```html
<?php
/**
 * The Header for our theme.
 *
 * Displays all of the <head> section
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Starkers
 * @since Starkers HTML5 3.0
 */
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head>
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>" />
<!-- Mobile Specific Metas
 ================================================== -->
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
<title><?php
 
    global $page, $paged;
 
    wp_title( '|', true, 'right' );
 
    bloginfo( 'name' );
 
    $site_description = get_bloginfo( 'description', 'display' );
    if ( $site_description && ( is_home() || is_front_page() ) )
        echo " | $site_description";
 
    if ( $paged >= 2 || $page >= 2 )
        echo ' | ' . sprintf( __( 'Page %s', 'starkers' ), max( $paged, $page ) );
 
    ?></title>
<link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="<?php bloginfo( 'stylesheet_url' ); ?>" />
<link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>" />
 
<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/modernizr-1.6.min.js"></script>

 
<?php
    /* We add some JavaScript to pages with the comment form
     * to support sites with threaded comments (when in use).
     */
    if ( is_singular() && get_option( 'thread_comments' ) )
        wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' );
 
    /* Always have wp_head() just before the closing </head>
     * tag of your theme, or you will break many plugins, which
     * generally use this hook to add elements to <head> such
     * as styles, scripts, and meta tags.
     */
    wp_head();
?>
</head>
 
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
 
    <header>



    
    <!-- Primary Page Layout 
 ================================================== -->
 <!-- globalWrapper -->
 <div id="globalWrapper">
  <header class="navbar-fixed-top">
   <!-- pre header -->
   
   <!-- pre header -->
   <!-- header -->
   <div id="mainHeader" role="banner">
    <div class="container">
     <nav class="navbar navbar-default scrollMenu" role="navigation">
      <div class="navbar-header">
       <!-- responsive navigation -->
       <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
       </button>
       <!-- Logo -->
                                                        
       <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/includes/images/logo.png" alt="blah"/></a>
      </div>
                                                
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="mainMenu">
       <!-- Main navigation -->
       <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
                                                            <li><a href="#">link 1</a></li>
                                                            <li><a href="#">link 2</a></li>
                                                            <li><a href="#">link 3</a></li>
                                                            <li><a href="#">link 4</a></li>
                                                            <li><a href="#">link 5</a></li>
                                                        </ul>
       <!-- End main navigation -->
      </div>
     </nav>
    </div>
   </div>
  </header>
         <!-- header -->
                        
        </header>
```

Part of the source code as viewed in Firefox:

```html
  </header>
         <!-- header -->
                        
        </header>                    
 

  <article id="post-4" class="post-4 page type-page status-publish hentry">
   <header>
         <h2><span class="hidepagetitles_toggle_title">home</span></h2>
       </header>    

    <div class="container">
<h3>Title</h3>
<p>sub title</p>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-8">
<p>There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don&#8217;t look even slightly believable. If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum, you need to be sure there isn&#8217;t anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text. All the Lorem Ipsum generators on the Internet tend to repeat predefined chunks as necessary, making this the first true generator on the Internet. It uses a dictionary of over 200 Latin words, combined with a handful of model sentence structures, to generate Lorem Ipsum which looks reasonable. The generated Lorem Ipsum is therefore always free from repetition, injected humour, or non-characteristic words etc.</p>
<p>There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don&#8217;t look even slightly believable. If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum, you need to be sure there isn&#8217;t anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text. All the Lorem Ipsum generators on the Internet tend to repeat predefined chunks as necessary, making this the first true generator on the Internet. It uses a dictionary of over 200 Latin words, combined with a handful of model sentence structures, to generate Lorem Ipsum which looks reasonable. The generated Lorem Ipsum is therefore always free from repetition, injected humour, or non-characteristic words etc.</p>
<p>There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don&#8217;t look even slightly believable. If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum, you need to be sure there isn&#8217;t anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text. All the Lorem Ipsum generators on the Internet tend to repeat predefined chunks as necessary, making this the first true generator on the Internet. It uses a dictionary of over 200 Latin words, combined with a handful of model sentence structures, to generate Lorem Ipsum which looks reasonable. The generated Lorem Ipsum is therefore always free from repetition, injected humour, or non-characteristic words etc.</p>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4"><img src="http://placehold.it/700x300" alt="" /></div>
</div>
</div>
      
          
   <footer>
       </footer>
  </article>

    


 <p></p>






 
 
 <!-- footer -->

       
  <footer id="footerWrapper">
   <section id="mainFooter">
```

Comment: You also have duplicate <header> in your header file. The file you have marked footer doesn't have your footer at all and has your <header> twice. Also your footerWrapper div comes after <footer> and that </article> close needs to go before footer. Show your actual header.php and footer.php files instead of source and I can try to find the problem.

Comment: Sorry, Here is the header:

Answer (score 0):

I took a look at your staging and you have 3 headers total. Find the globalWrapper div to find the first one inside it.

Most likely you have extra **get_header();** and **get_footer();** called somewhere, probably in a template part file that gets inserted into your index or page.php. Check out the loop-yourexample.php or meta files. You'll have to dig around. Do a search for header and footer calls in your files. The one inside article is most likely in the meta file that's bringing in the h1 title.